# Problem on Equilateral Triangle and points

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Equilateral $\triangle{ABC}$ with sides  $2\sqrt{3}$. Let $P$ be the point outside$\triangle{ABC}$ such that points $A$ and $P$ lie opposite to $BC$. Let $PD$, $PE$, $PF$ be the perpendicular dropped on side $BC$, $AC$ and $AB$ receptively where $D$, foot of perpendicular, lies inside the segment $BC$. Let $PD=2$. How to find $PE+PF$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviani%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of perpendiculars is altitude $H$ in case of an internal point P. If the point P lies outside and has length of *nearest* perpendicular  $h$ then the total of perpendicular distances is:

$$ altitude \,H + h = 3 +2 =5, $$

which can be verified by drawing perpendiculars on all three sides and calculating extra length parts in $ PE,PF$,over and above that for point $P$ when $on$ nearest side $BC.$ Shown in red color in a rough sketch $PD=h$ below.

EDIT1:

Angles $$ DPE = DPF = 60^0 $$

Red length total = $$ h (\cos 60^0 + \cos 60^0) = 2 ( \frac12 + \frac12) =2 $$

[image: Alt_EQ_tria]

Comment: how to calculate red part $=2$ ?

Comment: Please see above edit.